# How to refresh a page in a certain month. JS

Tags: javascript, date, datetime

I have a function that refreshes my page at a specific time and day but how can I refresh only on a specific month and date at a certain time? The reason why I want to do this is because my website checks for updates on football transfers that only takes place on specific months.

**Here is my function to refresh certain time in a day**

```
function refreshAt(hours, minutes, seconds, day) {
    var now = new Date();
    var then = new Date();
    var dayUTC = new Date();

    if(dayUTC.getUTCDay() == day) {

        if(now.getUTCHours() > hours ||
        (now.getUTCHours() == hours && now.getUTCMinutes() > minutes) ||
        now.getUTCHours() == hours && now.getUTCMinutes() == minutes && now.getUTCSeconds() >= seconds) {
            then.setUTCDate(now.getUTCDate() + 1);
        }

        then.setUTCHours(hours);
        then.setUTCMinutes(minutes);
        then.setUTCSeconds(seconds);


        var timeout = (then.getTime() - now.getTime());
        setTimeout(function() { window.location.reload(true); }, timeout);
    }
}
```

Comment: why cant you just add the month? `now.getMonth();` will give you the month.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've cleaned up your code a bit, and added in a line that would also let you set a specific date and month:

```
function refreshAt(hours, minutes, seconds, day, month) { // added month argument
    var now = new Date();
    var then = new Date( // used format: new Date(Y, M, D, h, m, s);
        now.getUTCFullYear(),
        month!=undefined ? month : now.getUTCMonth(),
        day,
        hours,
        minutes,
        seconds
    ); // fill in the date when defining the variable

    // You don't need a seperate Date object to get the UTC date

    if (now.getUTCDate() == day && (month == undefined || now.getUTCMonth() == month)) {
        if(now.getTime() > then.getTime()) {
            then.setUTCDate(now.getUTCDate() + 1);
        }

        // exit function if the new time is still after the current time
        if (now.getTime() > then.getTime()) return;

        // you don't need brackets around this
        var timeout = then.getTime() - now.getTime();
        setTimeout(function() { window.location.reload(true); }, timeout);
    }
}
```

I hope the comments make clear what modifications I made. If anything is still unclear, please leave a comment to this answer.

The line of `month!=undefined ? month : now.getUTCMonth(),` does the following:

If the month is *not* undefined, then fill in the month, and if it is not filled in, then use the current month. This means that using the following syntax would still work:

```
refreshAt(23, 59, 59, 30); //refreshes at 23:59:59 UTC today (30 Jan 2014)
```

### `Date` as parameter

You can also make this a bit easier by just supplying a `Date` object as a parameter, instead of each individual variable. That would look something like this:

```
function refreshAt(date) { // added month argument
    var now = new Date();

    if (now.getUTCDate() == date.getUTCDate()) {
        var timeout = date.getTime() - now.getTime();
        if (timeout > 0)
            setTimeout(function() { window.location.reload(true); }, timeout);
    }
}
```

This can then be called via

```
refreshAt(new Date(2014, 0, 30, 23, 59, 59));
```

This sets a refresh timer for 30 Jan 2014, 23:59:59 UTC.

Comment: Ok i see what you have done i guess i just put a variable in for undefined?

Comment: I've added an explanation.

Comment: @user3210416 I've updated it to a better working version. If you enter the date in the format `refreshAt(hours, minutes, seconds, date)` or `refreshAt(hours, minutes, seconds, date, month)` it will both work.

Comment: I'd suggest giving functions like these a `Date` argument, instead of 5 arguments in a very strange order,

Comment: @Rudie I was just building on the code OP provided me. I could add a seperate code that would allow that below though, hang on...

Comment: @Rudie I've updated the question, and also removed the fairly unnecessary checks when using a `Date` object as parameter.

Comment: I know. I was just meddling =) Or free advice.

Comment: The second js code works great, nice work both of you